# firebase is not creating the user (user.uid = null)

Tags: firebase, facebook, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implemente facebook signin in flutter, however, firebase does not create a 'uid'. Doesn't the firebase create a uid automatically?

it returns:

```
The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid
```

below is the sign in method:

```dart
Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook(BuildContext context) async {
  final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

  if(result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
    final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken.token);
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then((user) async {
          final graphResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me? 
     fields=name,picture,email&access_token=${result
              .accessToken.token}'));
          final Map profile = jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);
          if (profile != null){
            authService.createUser(name: name, email: email, dob: dob, sex: sex);
          }
          return user;
        });
    }
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Profile()));
    return null;
    }
```

The sign in method returns a facebook alert dialog requesting the permission to share email, when press continue red screen with the error appears. why is the firestore not creating the user? Thanks! I am not familiar with the system and just learning.

create user method in authServices:

```dart
    Future<bool> createUser(
      {String name,
      User user,
      String email,
      String password,
      String phone,
      String sex,
      String dob}) async {
    var res = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: '$email',
      password: '$password',
    );
    if ((res.user != null)) {
      await saveUserToFirestore(name, res.user, email, dob, phone, sex);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to get `user.uid`? I can't see it in the code.

Comment: i believe, user.uid is the firebase's unique identifier, created automatically. is it not? however, it is not creating the uid... i am confused

Comment: What I meant was where in the code are you trying to read/get the UID of user? Can you tell which part/line of code throws that error?

Comment: when it navigates to the Profile(). I just need to create a user with the FB credentials.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand your code you first login the user with Facebook and then again create a new user with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. If you use the same email for both the second one will fail and give you `null`.

To track the auth state for all providers use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

More about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Comment: oh, thats right! will use just print(profile) or something like that.